# Changing Bluemix Account Default region?

Tags: default, ibm-cloud, region

I created my Bluemix account with "US SOUTH" as region. Later I realized that I belong to the UK-Europe region, and I can change to it once I'm logged in.
However, every time when I come back and log on again I need to switch again to UK region, because I cannot make this region the default one for my account. The login process takes me to my account with "US South" selected by default.
Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following URL to login directly to Bluemix UK region:

https://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net

Complementing the answer with Bill Wentworth's suggestion, here's the direct UI info for all 3 regions -

- US South region: http://console.ng.bluemix.net
- Europe United Kingdom region: http://console.eu-gb.bluemix.net
- Australia Sydney region: http://console.au-syd.bluemix.net

The info comes from here: http://ng.bluemix.net/docs/overview/index.html

Comment: Just for additional reference, here's the direct UI info for all 3 regions  - 
US South region: console.ng.bluemix.net / Europe United Kingdom region: console.eu-gb.bluemix.net / Australia Sydney region: console.au-syd.bluemix.net      The info comes from here: https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/overview/index.html

Comment: Thanks Bill, I added your comment to my answer as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Works as expected :)

Comment: I rather have the option to set a default region myself.

Answer (score 0):

Read official [documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/CloudLogAnalysis/qa/cli_qa.html#cli_qa) here

You should use `api.ng.bluemix.net` for `US South` and `US East`