# Can I change my account's default region in IBM cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

When I tried ibmcloud target --cf to deploy my app on my IBMcloud account .. I got No organisation found error...

I even tried to create a new organization but got failed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxQ5E.jpg

After some debugging I got to know I have created my IBM cloud account in eu region(We have to select a location at the time of account creation) and I tried to deploy my app/creating the organization in us-south region that's why it was throwing error.

After that i changed my region in ibm console 
by
ibmcloud api https://api.eu-gb.bluemix.net

and login again.

and app gets deployed successfully.

I searched on google but havent got anything about how to change your default user account region.

I go through the link but seems like it will change my api endpoint to a specific region not my account's default region.
[Changing Bluemix Account Default region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125043/changing-bluemix-account-default-region)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ibmcloud target -r REGION_NAME

ibmcloud target -r us-south

Comment: is it possible to login to ibm cloud without specifying the target and region and use the tool to query about existing spaces in different regions?